# On convergence of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ , given that the sequence $\{x_{n+1}+f(x_n)\}$ converges for some function $f$ on real line

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $\{x_n\}$ is a real sequence such that the sequence $\{2x_{n+1}+\sin x_n\}$ is convergent , then is it true that $\{x_n\}$ convergent ?

Comment: I keep wondering why people upvote such questions without _any_ context, but I won't downvote it, I just have to ask: why are you asking this? Is it a real problem you met in a book or in your research, is it a challenge, or if not, what else is it?

Comment: $2x_{n+1}-1 \leq 2x_{n+1}+\sin x_n$. Take limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ on both sides.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 Why can you take that limit? Why is the LHS convergent?

Comment: Since $2x_{n+1}+\sin (x_n)$ is convergent it is bounded. Therefore $2x_{n+1}-1$ is bounded, hence $x_{n+1}$ is. Then $x_n$ has a convergent sub-sequence.

Comment: Why so, @uniquesolution?

Comment: @Spotty I agree, the fact that $(x_n)_n$ is bounded is immediate. Now why is the limit of that subsequence unique? Right now, without further detail I could use your argument to say that the sequence $((-1)^n)_n$ converges.

Comment: @ClementC. Took it back.

Comment: $sin(x)+2x$ is an increasing function so for every $c\in\mathbb R$ has a unique solution. If the limit of the sub-sequence is not unique you get a contradiction. My previous post was an hint anyway..

Comment: @Spotty I'm afraid you're wrong: the given property is about consecutive terms of the original sequence, and the convergent subsequence doesn't have to contain any of those.

Comment: @Spotty : that won't possibly work ; note that the quantity is $x_{n+1} +\sin x_n$ and not $x_n+ \sin x_n$ ... $\{x_{r_n} \}$ converges does not necessarily imply $\{ x_{1+r_n} \}$ converges

Comment: I would try this: Find $x\neq y$ such that $2x+\sin y=2y+\sin x$, if so you have a counterexample, the sequence $x,y,x,y,\ldots$

Comment: @Smurf This does not work: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2Bsin(y)%3D2y%2Bsin(x)+plot

Comment: @Smurf That can't work, because $|\sin x−\sin y|\le|x−y|,$ and the impossibility of such a counter-example let's me admit the claim could be correct. But it's not easy to prove, I guess.

Comment: Let $x_{n_k}$ and $x_{n_h}$ distinct converging sub-sequences (say converge to $a$ and $b$). Then the sequences $2x_{n_k}-\sin(x_{n_k+1})$ and $2x_{n_h}-\sin(x_{n_h+1})$ have the same-limit (they are sub-sequences of the converging thing). Then you have $2a-\sin a=2b-\sin b$ and you are done. Right @ProfessorVector?

Comment: Interesting mathematical problem (if only for all the wrong "answers" it caused), but why the total lack of context of the question?

Comment: @Spotty You can not guarantee that $\sin(x_{n_k +1})$ converges to $\sin a$. This is because $x_{n_k+1}$ does not necessarily converge to $a$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say $b = \lim 2x_{n+1} + \sin x_n$ and $a$ is the (unique) real number such that $2a + \sin a = b$. Then

$$0 = \lim_{n\to\infty} (2x_{n+1} + \sin x_n - 2a - \sin a) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \biggl(2(x_{n+1}-a) + 2\cos\frac{a+x_n}{2}\sin \frac{x_n-a}{2}\biggr).$$

Define $u_n = x_n - a$, then

$$v_n := u_{n+1} + \cos(a + u_n/2)\sin (u_n/2) \to 0.$$

We would like to conclude that $u_n \to 0$. Suppose that weren't the case, and

$$\eta := \limsup_{n\to \infty}\: \lvert u_n\rvert > 0.$$

We can without loss of generality assume that $\lvert v_n\rvert < \eta/8$ for all $n$. For every $n$ such that $\lvert u_{n+1}\rvert > 7\eta/8$, it then follows that

$$\frac{3}{4}\eta < \lvert u_{n+1} - v_n\rvert = \lvert \cos(a+u_n/2)\sin(u_n/2)\rvert \leqslant \frac{\lvert u_n\rvert}{2},$$

so

$$\lvert u_n\rvert > \frac{3}{2}\eta.$$

Since there are arbitrarily large $n$ such that $\lvert u_{n+1}\rvert > 7\eta/8$, we obtain the contradiction

$$\eta = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\: \lvert u_n\rvert \geqslant \frac{3}{2}\eta.$$

Answer (score 5):

By hypothesis, the sequence $(y_n)$ defined by $y_n=2x_{n+1}+\sin x_n$ converges to some finite limit. Furthermore, $x_{n+1}=\frac12y_n-\frac12\sin x_n$ and $-1\leqslant\sin x_n\leqslant1$ for every $n$, hence there exists $\ell_0\leqslant1.01$ and $a_0$ such that, for every $n$ large enough, $a_0\leqslant x_n\leqslant a_0+\ell_0$.

Now, assume that, for every $n$ large enough, $a_k\leqslant x_n\leqslant a_k+\ell_k$ for some given $\ell_k$ and $a_k$. Then, the image of any interval of length $\ell_k$ by the sine function has length at most $\ell_k$ hence, using the identity $x_{n+1}=\frac12y_n-\frac12\sin x_n$ once again, one sees that  there exists some $\ell_{k+1}\leqslant0.51\ell_k$ and $a_{k+1}$ such that, for every $n$ large enough, $a_{k+1}\leqslant x_n\leqslant a_{k+1}+\ell_{k+1}$.

The intersection $\bigcap\limits_k[a_k,a_k+\ell_k]$ is reduced to at most one point since $\ell_k\to0$. It remains to note that $(x_n)$ is bounded, hence $(x_n)$ has at least one limit point, to deduce that $(x_n)$ converges.

---

This approach proves the following more general result, whose statement might help to pinpoint the features of the present one that make it hold:

> Let $y_n=cx_{n+1}+f(x_n)$, for some fixed $c$ and $k$-Lipschitz function $f$, with $k<|c|$. If the sequence $(y_n)$ converges, then the sequence $(x_n)$ converges.